# How can I report a cheater in MW3?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

I don't know how to report players or hosts. Is there a way to do this?

I have the PC version that I've bought over Steam.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will depend on which platform you're playing on (hint: you should specify this in your question).

In the mean time, here is a guide for both consoles and Steam:

- [How to report cheaters in MW3](http://www.joinaclan.com/2011/11/cod-mw3-modern-warfare-3-how-to-report-hackers/)

Essentially, the PC version has no in-game function but you can find players you've recently played against through the Steam UI and report them from there. Consoles appear to have a dedicated button in-game.

No word on how successful either of these methods is, though.

Comment: I have PC version that I've bought over steam, tnx for the answer! But I still can't believe that such an expensive game with so many players all over the globe doesn't have better protection from cheaters! So sad!

Comment: @Davidenko yep, unfortunately it's increasingly common to find fewer and fewer official dedicated servers hosted by the publishers, even in such multiplayer-heavy series as CoD and Battlefield. Seems that as long as you buy the game and the map packs they don't particularly care whether the game environment deteriorates or not. </rant>

Comment: Well, if that is grounds for a VAC ban (you'd have to look it up) then it is sufficient punishment. PC developers are getting more into total Steam integration (whoo Borderlands 2 got nice integration compared to 1) and as such a VAC ban will start keeping them from playing multiplayer games that use Steam integration.

Comment: @Davidenko - the other thing you have to realise is that no (non-trivial) system is completely immune to hackers. This is especially so when (as Alex mentions) players are hosting games themselves and therefore have access to files that directly deal with game mechanics. Now all they need is the know-how to backwards-engineer them and get it to run their own code (which they would be pretty terrible hackers if they didn't know that). What's more with CoD in particular, because they haven't changed the game engine much, most of the old hacks still work in the newer games.

Comment: @Robotnik What! Newer CoD games created with minimal effort to renew and re-invigorate the series? Say it ain't so! (I got really fed up with the games, if you can't tell :P)

Comment: oh, whoops i forgot my <rant></rant> tags :P